# Balises desapear with Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have to do a form without using the Symfony template but when I submit it the balises are shifting to : `&lt; &quot;&gt;&lt` etc.

Here an example of the source code:

```
<form id="form_result" method="post" action="traitement.php">
                            <h4 class="result_google"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>Résultats de Google Scholar</h3>
    <a class="lien" href="http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=fr&amp;q=Histoire+de+France" target="_blank">http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=fr&amp;q=Histoire+de+France</a></br></br>
                            </br>&lt;div class=&quot;float_checkbox&quot;&gt;&lt;input class=&quot;result_scrap&quot; type=&quot;checkbox&quot; name=&quot;choix[]&quot; value=&quot;&lt;a href=&#039;&#039; class=&#039;result_title&#039; target=&#039;_blank&#039;&gt;[CITATION] [C]   Histoire de France&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;span class=&#039;result_author&#039;&gt; J Michelet - 1879 - C. Marpon et E. Flammarion&lt;/span&gt;&quot; /&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;choix&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;&quot; class=&quot;result_title&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;[CITATION] [C]   Histoire de France&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;result_author&quot;&gt; J Michelet - 1879 - C. Marpon et E. Flammarion&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/label&gt;
                            </br>&lt;div class=&quot;float_checkbox&quot;&gt;&lt;input class=&quot;result_scrap&quot; type=&quot;checkbox&quot; name=&quot;choix[]&quot; value=&quot;&lt;a href=&#039;http://www.mediterranee-antique.fr/Fichiers_PdF/JKL/Lavisse/HF_T72.pdf&#039; class=&#039;result_title&#039; target=&#039;_blank&#039;&gt;[LIVRE] [B]   Histoire de France&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;span class=&#039;result_author&#039;&gt; E Lavisse, A Green, REG Vaillant - 1923 - mediterranee-antique.fr&lt;/span&gt;&quot; /&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;choix&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.mediterranee-antique.fr/Fichiers_PdF/JKL/Lavisse/HF_T72.pdf&quot; class=&quot;result_title&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;[LIVRE] [B]   Histoire de France&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;result_author&quot;&gt; E Lavisse, A Green, REG Vaillant - 1923 - mediterranee-antique.fr&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/label&gt;
                            </br>&lt;div class=&quot;float_checkbox&quot;&gt;&lt;input class=&quot;result_scrap&quot; type=&quot;checkbox&quot; name=&quot;choix[]&quot; value=&quot;&lt;a href=&#039;http://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&amp;amp;lr=&amp;amp;id=4gP0S1FTxDcC&amp;amp;oi=fnd&amp;amp;pg=PT656&amp;amp;dq=Histoire+de+France&amp;amp;ots=f87ZSlo-Uz&amp;amp;sig=_o2oTsGrGSqr_efEiCOJkxx_YTk&#039; class=&#039;result_title&#039; target=&#039;_blank&#039;&gt;[LIVRE] [B]   Histoire de France&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;span class=&#039;result_author&#039;&gt; J Bainville - 2012 - books.google.com&lt;/span&gt;&quot; /&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;choix&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&amp;amp;lr=&amp;amp;id=4gP0S1FTxDcC&amp;amp;oi=fnd&amp;amp;pg=PT656&amp;amp;dq=Histoire+de+France&amp;amp;ots=f87ZSlo-Uz&amp;amp;sig=_o2oTsGrGSqr_efEiCOJkxx_YTk&quot; class=&quot;result_title&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;[LIVRE] [B]   Histoire de France&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;result_author&quot;&gt; J Bainville - 2012 - books.google.com&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/label&gt;
                            </br>&lt;div class=&quot;float_checkbox&quot;&gt;&lt;input class=&quot;result_scrap&quot; type=&quot;checkbox&quot; name=&quot;choix[]&quot; value=&quot;&lt;a href=&#039;http://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&amp;amp;lr=&amp;amp;id=9uAvAAAAMAAJ&amp;amp;oi=fnd&amp;amp;pg=PA163&amp;amp;dq=Histoire+de+France&amp;amp;ots=YVcqWEIHtY&amp;amp;sig=5-fzmMxuUR1vw9eymtNpcpNvgSA&#039; class=&#039;result_title&#039; target=&#039;_blank&#039;&gt;[LIVRE] [B]   Histoire de France&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;span class=&#039;result_author&#039;&gt; H Martin - 1860 - books.google.com&lt;/span&gt;&quot; /&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;choix&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&amp;amp;lr=&amp;amp;id=9uAvAAAAMAAJ&amp;amp;oi=fnd&amp;amp;pg=PA163&amp;amp;dq=Histoire+de+France&amp;amp;ots=YVcqWEIHtY&amp;amp;sig=5-fzmMxuUR1vw9eymtNpcpNvgSA&quot; class=&quot;result_title&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;[LIVRE] [B]   Histoire de France&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;result_author&quot;&gt; H Martin - 1860 - books.google.com&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/label&gt;
```

Here is my twig template code:

```
{% block body %}
<h2>Selectionnez les resultats que vous souhaitez conserver :</h2>
    <section id="section_result" class="row">   
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-6" id="section_body">
            <h3 id="result_query">Résultats pour votre recherche : {{ research }}</h3>
            <form id="form_result" method="post" action="traitement.php">
            {# SCRAPING GOOGLE SCHOLAR #}
            {% if resultat1 is defined %}
                <h4 class="result_google"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>Résultats de Google Scholar</h3>
                <a class="lien" href="{{ googleURL }}" target="_blank">{{ googleURL }}</a></br></br>
                {% for result1 in resultat1 %}
                        </br>{{ result1 }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

Do you know what is the problem? How can I resolve it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Add your twig template code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your values escaped, use [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) in your twig template;

```
{{ result1|raw }} {# result1 won't be escaped #}
```